# Device detecting Conditional css

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I am trying to add some conditional css for device detecting, because of some conflicts in desktop and android tablet landscape res

```
- if android_device?
        :css

          @media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2)  {

            /*CSS*/
          }
```

can any one help me out where I have to use this check?

I got this reference from this url:
[URL](http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/using-css-media-queries-for-multi-platform/)

Comment: if android_device? - what is this?

Comment: Only Microsoft think: 'we usually get it wrong, so lets include a way for devs to fix our issues'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of detecting an operating system or web browser using strictly CSS.

I'd recommend using Javascript to detect the web browser / operating system, and attach classes to the `<body>` of the page accordingly.

You can then write CSS specific to each use case, which will only be honored if that particular criteria is encountered.

Here is an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKCXQ/4/).

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a nice way I found useful which is to use conditional media queries in your HTML as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 640px)" href="max-640px.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 640px)" href="min-640px.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: landscape)" href="landscape.css">
</head>
</html>
```

I believe it solves your problem

Source: [github.com/googlesamples/web-fundamentals](https://github.com/googlesamples/web-fundamentals/blob/93e9ebc3855f75f19079009d7bc38cfd0d2336b4/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/media-queries.html)

Answer (score -7):

Following code is invalid css:

```
- if android_device?
        :css
```

If you want to write specific styles for desktop and android devices then:

1) you can directly include desktop styles without any media query in css.

2)Styles which ar specific to android device can be included in between media queries as

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 800px) {

  /*CSS  */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address detecting android devices, only screen width.